# AWS CLI EC2 describe-instances command; how does the `ip-address` filter work?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I am learning how to use the CLI tool for AWS and I come across this command:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=ip-address,Values=my.test.ip.address"
```

The command works fine and I can see the EC2 instance details in the command output, however, it does not have any field with the name `ip-address`. Instead, it has `PublicIp` and `PublicIpAddress` fields that contain the ip address which I am looking for.

How does this filter work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a list of keys which can be used to filter on. This can be found in the documentation for the `describe-instances` command: [`--filter`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-instances.html#options). One of them `ip-address`:

> `ip-address` - The public IPv4 address of the instance.

I did not take a look on the source code for the `describe-instances`, but I believe it parses the JSON response and it has a preconfigured path for each of the filters.

**Update:**

After takin a look at the source code if `aws-cli` on [GitHub](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli), all the commands are transformed into API calls and send to AWS. All the filtering is happening in the back-end.